# Every time I try to run this code the iPhone Crashes

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, nsarray, ibaction

So, I'm trying to run this code in my iPhone App but the app keeps on crashing. Any solutions?

```
- (IBAction)logOutBtnDown:(id)sender {
    [PFUser logOut];
    NSArray *quotes;
    int r;

    quotes = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
        @"R u done yet",
        @"Log in again",
        @"Try Me",
        @"SMD",
        @"We can do this all day",
        @"IDC your eating up ur RAM",
        "Please just connect to the servers",
        @"You are not giving up are u",
        @"Forget it I quit",
        @"Imma tell TDK",
        nil];

    r = arc4random() % 10;
    [_welcomeLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@" %@", [quotes objectAtIndex: r]]];
}
```

Comment: tell me where exactly the crash occurs?

Comment: use `arc4random_uniform`instand of `arc4random()`

Comment: can you tell what is the exact crashing error shown by console?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Missed placing @,while adding object..

try this one..

```
- (IBAction)logOutBtnDown:(id)sender {
  [PFUser logOut];
NSArray *quotes;
int r;

quotes = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"R u done yet", @"Log in again", @"Try Me", @"SMD", @"We can do this all day", @"IDC your eating up ur RAM", @"Please just connect to the servers", @"You are not giving up are u", @"Forget it I quit", @"Imma tell TDK", nil];

r = arc4random() % 10;


[_welcomeLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@" %@", [quotes objectAtIndex: r]]];

}
```